# Sources of GeoJSON (offline) maps for waterways/harbors

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers-3, geojson

I am building an application that needs to plot ships on a map. It needs to work offline. So far I have been getting maps from http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/, converted these to JSON, and then used added the JSON files to layers in OpenLayers 3.

I can now see fairly detailed outlines of coast, rivers, etc. However, I am missing the large water inlets/harbors. These would be quite nice, since this is where the ships tend to dock ;-)

I've tried some data sources from OpenStreetmaps, but they are not helping. They also seem to be missing the waterways.

Can anyone point me in the direction of an offline source for waterway/harbors/water inlets?

Thanks!

Comment: Which information is missing from OpenStreetMap? Depending on the area there should be various [harbor features](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Harbour) mapped, including the harbor itself, piers, docks, slipways, boatyards, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your comment scai. The json file for the detailed version of open street maps was over a GB and I had performance issues with that. The generalized version was worse than natural earth data. As mentioned, I need to work from an offline source.

Comment: You can define exactly which features the OSM extract should contain. Either by filtering it afterwards via [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) or [osmfilter](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter), or by using [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) and specifying excactly which elements to download.

Comment: Thanks again. I have had a little time to explore the options now. Even just exporting a few element for the entire world would lead to a file size to large to use as a GeoJSON layer directly. I think I would need to implement some sort of local Tile server which is out of scope of the project.